# How to fix userform which inserts data into separate worksheet but leaves two blank rows between each entry, despite code to insert to next blank row?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform which is designed to insert data into sheets called "Final tours" and "Splits", but in different ways.

I select a row in "Final Tours", click a button to "Split Tour", and enter the new tour details. Then it copies the new tour details onto the bottom of "Final Tours" (this works fine), and deletes the original row. It is meant to also copy the data onto "Splits". However, in "Splits", while it enters the data on the row correctly, each time I enter new data to the userform, it leaves two blank rows from the previous row.

So If I split three tours, on "Splits" it would display the data on rows 1, 4, 7 etc. instead of 1, 2, 3. I can't figure out why it's doing this. Any thoughts? My code is below:

```
Option Explicit
Dim originalRow As Range

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set originalRow = ActiveCell.EntireRow
    With Me
        .OriginalTourCode.Value = originalRow.Cells(1).Value
        .OriginalStartDate.Value = originalRow.Cells(2).Value
        .OriginalEndDate.Value = originalRow.Cells(3).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub SplitTourCommand_Click()

    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim wsSplits As Worksheet
    Set wsSplits = Sheets("Splits")
    Dim wsTours As Worksheet
    Set wsTours = Sheets("Final Tours")
    Dim WSheet As Variant
    Dim DTable As Variant, RowCount As Long

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save

    For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsTours.AutoFilterMode Then
            If wsTours.FilterMode Then
                wsTours.ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
        For Each DTable In wsTours.ListObjects
            If DTable.ShowAutoFilter Then
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
            End If
        Next DTable
    Next WSheet

    With wsSplits.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
            With .Offset(2, 0).EntireRow
                .Cells(1) = OriginalTourCode.Text
                .Cells(2) = OriginalStartDate.Text
                .Cells(3) = OriginalEndDate.Text
                .Cells(4) = NewTourCode1.Text
                .Cells(5) = NewStartDate1.Text
                .Cells(6) = NewEndDate1.Text
                .Cells(7) = NewTourCode2.Text
                .Cells(8) = NewStartDate2.Text
                .Cells(9) = NewEndDate2.Text
                .Cells(10) = ReasonForSplit.Text
                .Cells(11).Value = Date

            End With
        End With

        With wsTours.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = NewTourCode1.Text
            .Offset(1, 1).Value = NewStartDate1.Text
            .Offset(1, 2).Value = NewEndDate1.Text
            .Offset(2, 0).Value = NewTourCode2.Text
            .Offset(2, 1).Value = NewStartDate2.Text
            .Offset(2, 2).Value = NewEndDate2.Text
        End With

        originalRow.Delete 'remove the row the split tour

        MsgBox "Tour " & OriginalTourCode.Text & _
        " has been split to " & NewTourCode1.Text & _
        " and " & NewTourCode2.Text

        Unload Me

    End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CloseCommand_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are using `Rows.Count` to select where you are inserting the new data, but because you do not specify the sheet, it takes the `Rows.Count` of active sheet. That could explain your problem. Try being more specific. Something like `wsSplits.Cells(wsSplits.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)` maybe could fix your problem.

Comment: Why are you `offset`ting twice? You've got `With .Offset(1,0).EntireRow` followed by `With .Offset(2,0).EntireRow`. Why not just `With .Offset(3,0).EntireRow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have posted a lot of code, which makes it hard to give a full answer. Instead I will give you a few hints on how to make your code easier to follow and debug.
This part:

```
With wsSplits.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        With .Offset(2, 0).EntireRow
```

is probably the culprit. Offsets from offsets from a row that might not be the last row according to your expectation is tricky. Instead I think you should store the row number in a variable:

```
NewRow = wsSplits.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

and then work from there, like

```
wsSplits.Cells(NewRow + 1, "A")...
```

Comment: You could just as easily use `Offset`. So instead of `Cells....` you can use `.Offset(1,1).Value2 = OriginalTourCode.Text`

Comment: I think the whole point of the original question was that it is easy getting lost if you rely too much on offsets. I wanted to show an alternative.